# Adding a facebook page tab using Facebook PHP SDK v5

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a facebook application. Using php code to adding a tab in the Facebook page. And I want to change 'Secure Page Tab URL' for tab on the same App but I don't know how to do it!

Example: 
tab A -> Secure Page Tab URL A / tab B -> Secure Page Tab URL B

Does any one have an idea about this? thanks!

Comment: Not Clear What you are saying?

Comment: I read Pages API for resolve this problem, but I don't know how to do it! 
'Integrating with Facebook APIs' https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/tabs

Comment: You want to change the URL ?

Comment: I want to change Secure Page Tab URL, show different content on different Pages depending on it but i don't know how to do it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only have one Secure Page Tab URL per App. If you want to show different content on different Pages, you have to parse the `signed_request` POST parameter to get the Page ID - and show different content depending on that ID.

More information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook/login#parsingsr

Btw, it is not possible to add one App several times to one Page, just in case that´s what you want to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Example: I haved Page ID but I don't know how to show different content depending on it, this is my code:
 $addTab = $fb->post('/' . $page['id'] . '/tabs', array( 'app_id' => '123456789', 'position' => '1', 'custom_name' => 'Tab 1', 'custom_image_url' => 'localhost/app/';, ), $page['access_token']);

Comment: that is just the code to add an app to a page. you have to check for the signed_request POST parameter in the iframe, when it is on the page. add a var_dump($_POST['signed_request']) in your page and you will see it. parse it with the function in the link of my answer and you will get the page id.